# Set Asp.Net ImageUrl from Network drive in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to set the ImageURl of my aspx page in the code behind and the image is not getting displayed. I tried creating an ashx handler as well. Below is the config entry related to ashx

and below is the code in HttpHandler.cs file

```
public bool IsReusable
    {
        // Return false in case your Managed Handler cannot be reused for another request.
        // Usually this would be false in case you have some state information preserved per request.
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string imgName = context.Request.QueryString["n"];
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/tiff";
        string path = "\\mynetwork\\PBTestData\\";
        Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
        image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Tiff);
    }
```

And I am trying to set the ImageUrl property in my code behind file as below
    myImage.ImageUrl = "ImageHandler.ashx?n=LT702474_W24_D1.tiff";

All this I am trying from my local machine in debug mode and not for yet from local IIS server, which I should be doing in near future. A

Please let me know what are the steps I need to follow to display the image from my local machine as well when I publish this on IIS server.

Comment: Finally, I was able to make some changes and was able to load the image. But the issue is the image is not displaying in the given width and height. I have the aspx code as follows <td style="width:818px; height:757px" >
                        <div style="padding-top: 10px; width:818px; height:757px">
                            <asp:Image ID="DieImage" runat="server" Width="818px" Height="757px" />
                        </div>
                    </td>

Comment: I also added the Content-Length in the Handler code as belowstring imgName = context.Request.QueryString["n"];
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/bmp";
                string path = @"\\mynetwork\\PBAppData\\" + imgName;
                Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", image.Height.ToString());
                image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);